# Is there a way to mathematically transform any given number into 1 but keep the original number's signal?

Tags: functions, transformation

I was wondering if there is a purely mathematical way to, given any number, transform this number into the number one, keeping the original number's signal. Something like:

- f(-4) = -1
- f(5) = 1
- f(-2.5) = -1
- f(pi) = 1
- (. . .)

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean $f(x)=\frac {|x|}x$ for $x\neq 0$?

Comment: Yes, dumb question indeed. I knew from the start that the answer would be simple like that, but somehow my brain stopped working and I wasn't finding any solution for the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You are probably confusing "purely mathematical way" with "expressible using certain expressions". There is nothing stopping you from defining: $f \colon {\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}$ by $f(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$, $f(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$, and $f(x) = -1$ if $x < 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the function *sign* which can be defined like this:

$$\mathrm{sgn}\colon x\mapsto \mathrm{sgn}(x)=\frac {\vert x\vert}x.$$

Its graph is:

[image]